# How to serialize and deserialize errors string in go

Tags: go

In the context of two go services sharing the same types, one client post a json to a server:

```
type Message struct {
   Error string `json:"error"`
}
```

The client should serialize an `error` into a string.

The server should deserialize that string into an `error` on which I can use `errors.As` or `errors.Is` to check for wrapped errors and such.

How may I serialize nested errors ?

Comment: Have a look at the [Unmarshaler](https://pkg.go.dev/encoding/json#Unmarshaler) interface. You can create your own type (just a string alias) for your error and implement `Unmarshaler`. You will need two fields or types to be able to marshal to a `string` but unmarshal to an `error`.

Comment: this would not cover nested errors though would it ?

Comment: Not automatically, you would need to parse the string to figure that out or use a different format for the json representation.

Comment: *"Is it possible to do that"* -- Yes. *"and if so, is there existing library for that purpose?"* -- asking for recommendations is off topic on SO (see item number 3. in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 1):

Let me share with you some thoughts that maybe can guide you in the right direction.

#### `errors.Is` and `errors.As`

These two operators deal with the `error` type. The common scenario they are used when you've to deal with an `error` returned by a function and, based on which type of error it is, take some actions. If you're returning just a string from a function, it's almost impossible to invoke `errors.Is` and `errors.As` unless you do some extra logic to handle the string.

#### A simple workaround

If you wanna preserve a hierarchical structure for your errors without having to flatten them, you could follow this approach:

```golang
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type RecursiveErr struct {
    Message string `json:"Message"`
    Err     error  `json:"error"`
}

func (r RecursiveErr) Error() string {
    return r.Message
}

func main() {
    // recursive - marshal
    childErr := RecursiveErr{Message: "leaf-child error"}
    parentErr := RecursiveErr{Message: "root error", Err: &childErr}
    data, _ := json.MarshalIndent(&parentErr, "", "\t")
    fmt.Println(string(data))

    // recursive - unmarshal
    var parsedParentErr RecursiveErr
    json.Unmarshal(data, &parsedParentErr)
    fmt.Println(parsedParentErr.Message)
}
```

This solution has the following benefits:

1. You can preserve the hierarchical structure of your errors (parent-child relationship)
2. You can invoke the `errors.Is` and `errors.As` on the `Err` field.

As it's an uncommon scenario for me, I hope to not be off-topic with your request, let me know!